# The speed connection drops down after a few months

Tags: macbook-pro, network, usb, thunderbolt

I don't understand what's the deal with USB-C Ethernet adapter and dock.

I bought many USB-C Ethernet adapters and docks (for  example Anker USB Type-C to Ethernet, USB C Hub 8 in 1, uni USB-C, Hyper Drive GEN2 12-in-1 USB-C Dock) and I always hand up getting an issue with the NIC.

Every time I'm getting a normal speed at the beginning of 940Mbps+, after a few months, (even faster for the Hyper Drive), the speed is dropping drastically to 100/120Mbps.

Just to clarify, there is no network issue, no Ethernet cable issue. When the same switch/port/VLAN is connected to another client, I get the full speed.

I initially thought it was an issue with the Thunderbolt 3 port of my MacBook Pro 2019 16inch. I sent it back to Apple, but they couldn't replicate the issue. (I don't think they would have a gigabit WAN to test, and I really doubt they would do a iPerf.)

I don't know what to do now. Should I only buy thunderbolt 3 docks/adaptors, and avoid USB-C (non Thunderbolt)? (It's all over 300€ if I want to keep PD which is 96W, in my case.)

Comment: I'm just curious on how you are testing the network speed, what is your testing process?  I'd also want to rule out a confusion on bits vs. bytes.  120 megaBYTES is 960 megaBITS and if you are confusing the units then the problem is just an illusion.

Comment: I'm using iPerf 3, but I have similar result with CloudFlare speed test (even through HTML) and Speedtest app.